# Retrofit POST request - parsing two JSON Objects having same name

Tags: android, json, post, kotlin, retrofit

i am using retrofit for upload data to web service and i am getting response from web service accordingly. Upload data has following structure.

[image]

and response contains following structure.

[image]

As you can see upload data and response both contains `data` named object. So, my question is how can i make Model Class for handling this request and response 
`data` object?.

I am doing it as follow but it gives error of `multiple fields having same name`.

```
data class PostDataModel(var data: PostDataFieldsModel,var status: String, var message: String,
                     @SerializedName("data") var data1: PostResponseDataFieldsModel)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You should make one model for request and a different one for responses

Comment: Yes, i have also thought that. I have done that then i can't understand how can i pass those two in POST request using Retrofit. Please you can provide me any example or any helpful  link? @LeviAlbuquerque

Comment: @JaydipKalkani You should have your data model representing the request as a parameter, while the response will be embedded in the return type (e.g., in a `Call` object if you're using plain Retrofit)

Comment: @JaydipKalkani checkout the answer, hope it helps you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a model POJO for each response and request. For example, you might have the following endpoint in retrofit:

```
@Headers({"Content-Type: application/json", "Accept: application/json"})
@POST("/login")
Call<Response<LoginResponse>> login(
        @Body LoginRequest request);
```

**LoginRequest.java**

```
public class LoginRequest {
    DataModel data;

//getters and setters

}
```

**LoginResponse.java**

```
public class LoginResponse {

   Integer status;
   String message;
   SecondDataModel data;

  //getters and setters
}
```

You `DataModel` class should model the data field in the request. And your `SecondDataModel` should model the one in the response. If they have the same data, you can use the same POJO.

Comment: +1 for the clean explanation. I have changed my code according to your suggestion. Now, my error is gone but my web service returns me some error. Once i will make sure that i get correct response from web service then i will mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: I am using POSTMAN for testing my web service and it returns correct response but when i post the same data using android, my web service returns `Please pass the language type` as error message but i have passed language type correctly. So, i have to figure it out that their is a mistake in posting data or it's somewhere else. It will be great if you can provide me any hint.

Comment: Maybe your api requires yout to add the "Accept-Language" header. Add "Accept-Language", "Your value" in the @Header collection in the endpoint

Comment: No. My api doesn't require any "Accept-Language" header. I can say that surely because in POSTMAN i am not passing any header.

Comment: lang_type, are you setting that? In your post data?

Comment: Yes, I am setting `lang_type` in post data.

Comment: can you please tell me that how the `LoginRequest` model class structure should be? It should contain `data` object of any other model class type which contains my all login data fields or it should directly contains login data fields and having name `data` instead of `request`?

Comment: I got the answer. It should contain `data` object of model class type which contains my all login fields data. Thank you very much for your great answer. You saved my day. I have been facing it since last 2 days. Thank you very much.